# VSTO Outlook: Rename Add-in

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an Outlook VSTO Add-in which had a name and now I am tying to rename it to another one.

There are several places where i don't figure out how to change it.

1. Outlook Splash screen, when starting Outlook that says: "Loading Add-ins (x of y)" and under it it appears my Add-in name.
   [image]
2. In the list of Add-ins in Outlook Options: [image]
3. In the Slow and disabled-Add-ins [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FriendlyName` windows registry key is a descriptive name of the VSTO Add-in that is displayed in the `COM Add-Ins` dialog box in the Microsoft Office application. The default value is the VSTO Add-in ID. See [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022) for more information.

If you are dealing with VSTO based add-ins you may check out the *.vsto file content where such information is kept:

```
<description asmv2:publisher="OutlookAddIn7" asmv2:product="OutlookAddIn7" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
```

Comment: Also I see that the assembly name is required to change. Project -> Solution explorer -> Properties -> Application tab -> Change the assembly name.

Also, as far as I know, the .vsto file is generated automatically by Visual Studio when you build the Outlook VSTO Add-in, there's no need to edit it.

Comment: Correct. In case of COM add-ins you need to use the ProgID attribute if your add-in class.